# React Native WebView onMessage and postMessage to get all web page

Tags: react-native, webview

I don't really clear how to implement `onMessage` and `postMessage`, can I get whole web page but only from react native side.

I mean, I will inject this code using `injectedJavaScript`

```
var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML
window.postMessage(markup)
```

and I will receive the result using `onMessage`. Is it posible cause so far I can't do that

Answer (score 5):

yes you can do this all you to have to do is use `window.postMessage("message")` from your web-page that is going to load in `WebView` and you can see that message in `onMessage` prop.

**Example:**

```
class Test extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state:{
            html:''
        }
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({
            html : `<html>
    <head>
    <script>
    window.postMessage("Messga from webView")
    </script>
    </head>
    <body><h1>Hello from webView</h1></body>
    </html>`
        })
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <WebView
                    ref={(reff) => {
                        this.webView = reff;
                    }}
                    source={{html: this.state.html}}
                    style={[styles.flex1, styles.padding5]}
                    onMessage={(event)=>{
                        let message  = event.nativeEvent.data;
                        /* event.nativeEvent.data must be string, i.e. window.postMessage
                        should send only string.
                        * */
                    }}
                    onNavigationStateChange={(evt)=>{}}
                    onError={(e) => {
                        console.warn('error occured', e)
                    }}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

I just added a sample html and rendered it in `WebView`, you can do the same in your page that you are going to load in `WebView`.

**Or another solution is:**

You can use `injectedJavaScript` or `injectJavaScript` props of `WebView`  as described [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.49/docs/webview.html#injectjavascript).

Answer (score 4):

`postMessage` is deprecated :: and now you have to use `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(data)`

```js
const injectedJavascript = `(function() {
  window.postMessage = function(data) {
    window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(data);
  };
})()`;
```

for a full imagination of a component will be:

```js
export const WebViewComponent = (props) => {
  const webViewScript = `
    setTimeout(function() { 
      window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(/*your pushed data back to onMessage 'event.nativeEvent.data'*/); 
    }, 2500);
    true; // note: this is required, or you'll sometimes get silent failures
  `;

  return (
    <WebView
      source={{
        uri: `https://example.com`,
      }}
      automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
      scrollEnabled={false}
      onMessage={(event) => {
        // do something with `event.nativeEvent.data`
      }}
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      injectedJavaScript={webViewScript}
      domStorageEnabled={true}
      style={{ width: "100%", height: /*webViewHeight*/ }}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: `onMessage ` can we receive any action in `webview` generated on `webpage` in react native by injecting script I am able to receive but not generated by `webPage`

Answer (score 0):

Actually
i was looking at the documentation since i use the injectJavascript function of the react native´s webview. And in here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage , it says that for extensions we need to use a "*" as a property .
So it wouldn´t be like this "window.postMessage("Messga from webView")"

Instead it will need to be  window.postMessage("Messga from webView","*") to work.